# Laravel 5 - Issue with design and data in edit page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am having issues with one of my edit pages, and I am not too sure if it is down to my database design.
I have set up the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/33/) which demonstrates my create form

Now my first schema captures the simple information from that page, basically just the value of the radio button choice 
and the date input.

```
Schema::create('campaign_creatives', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('templateOptions')->default('')->nullable();
    $table->date('arrival')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now if you select a number from one of the select boxes, you will see that number of text inputs appear.  It is the 
data within this I am interested in.  Additionally, if you select the Dynamic radio button, additional inputs appear.
Furthermore, if you select Other, a text area appears to provide further details.  SO I wanted a way to capture all this
information, and I created the following table

```
Schema::create('campaign_creatives_data', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->default('')->nullable();
    $table->string('label')->default('')->nullable();
    $table->longText('value')->default('')->nullable();
    $table->integer('campaignCreativesId')->unsigned()->default(0);
    $table->foreign('campaignCreativesId')->references('id')->on('campaign_creatives')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The name would represent the thing I am capturing, while the label and value represents the input label and value.
After all this, when I save data, it looks a bit like the following

```
campaign_creatives
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | campaignType | creativeArrival | campaignId | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 14 | Dynamic      | 2016-02-25      |          2 | 2016-02-23 15:56:43 | 2016-02-23 15:56:43 |
+----+--------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+

campaign_creatives_data
+----+----------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name           | label             | value        | campaignCreativesId | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 62 | creativeOption | Other             | dfsdfsdfsdf  |                  14 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 |
| 60 | creativeOption | checkboxSelection | Pizza        |                  14 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 |
| 61 | creativeOption | checkboxSelection | Lemondade    |                  14 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 |
| 59 | creativeNumber | Food2             |              |                  14 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 |
| 57 | creativeNumber | Drink2            | Some input   |                  14 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 |
| 58 | creativeNumber | Food1             | Some input   |                  14 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 |
| 56 | creativeNumber | Drink1            | Some input   |                  14 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 | 2016-02-23 16:00:01 |
+----+----------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

creativeOption represents the checkboxes, creativeNumber represents the data relating to Number of Choices.  So to produce the 
above in the FIddle, I would choose 2 for Food and Drink and in the text boxes that appear enter Some input (apart from one which is left empty).
I would choose Dynamic and select the Pizza, Lemonade and Other checkboxes.  In the textarea for the Other checkbox, I entered dfsdfsdfsdf
(so for the other checkbox, I am interested in the textbox data rather than the checkbox value).

In regards to my Models, a CampaignCreatives can have many CampaignCreativesData.  So everything for the creating side of things works great.
The issue comes with the edit page, seeing that a lot of the display is dynamic.  I pass the view this

```
$campaignCreative = CampaignCreatives::where('campaignId', '=', $campaign->id)->first();
```

I use first because there can only be one CampaignCreatives.  Within my view, I now have access to all that data displayed above.  Here is an example.
On my edit page, I have the following which represents the Number of Options select boxes.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Number of Options</h3>
            <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
                {!! Form::label('cFood', 'Food:', array('class' => '')) !!}
                {!! Form::select('cFood', ['0' => '0', '1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5', '6' => '6', '7' => '7'], null, ['class' => 'cSelectType']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {!! Form::label('cDrink', 'Drink:', array('class' => '')) !!}
                {!! Form::select('cDrink', ['0' => '0', '1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5', '6' => '6', '7' => '7'], null, ['class' => 'cSelectType']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {!! Form::label('cOther', 'Other:', array('class' => '')) !!}
                {!! Form::select('cOther', ['0' => '0', '1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5', '6' => '6', '7' => '7'], null, ['class' => 'cSelectType']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From the above data, I know that there are 4 creativeNumber data, 2 for Food and 2 for Drink.  Therefore, I need the text inputs displayed for these with their value.
How would I go about doing something like this?

I know this is a lot of information, I would be so greatful if someone could guide me in the correct direction.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you insert a properly `hasMany `relationship in the `CampaignCreative` model towards `CampaignCreativeData` model?

Comment: Yes, the relationships are set up correctly

Comment: Can you provide JSON data of `$campaignCreative` variable that you are passing to your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd change the way that you're storing the labels, so that instead of having Food1, Food2, Food3 etc, you
simply have 'Food'. This way you can have many `Foods` per `CampaignCreatives`.

This will allow you to add a few additional relationships on your CampaignCreatives model to target those types:

```
public function foods()
{
    return $this->hasMany('CreativeCampaignData::class')->whereHas('type', function($query) {
        $query->where('campaign_creatives_data.name', 'Food');
    });
}
```

You can do the same for `Drinks` and `Other`.

Then, you can eager load the related data as such:

```
$campaignCreative = CampaignCreatives::with('foods', 'drinks', 'others')->where('campaignId', $campaign->id)->firstOrFail();
```

Then to generate the form, use:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Number of Options</h3>
            <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">

                @foreach($campaignCreative->foods as $food)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Food {{ $food->id }}:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="foods[{{ $food->id }}]" value="{{ old('foods.'.$food->id, $food->id) }}" />
                    </div>
                @endforeach

            </div>

            <!-- other fields here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't test the code as it has been written in isolation of the rest of your application, but this should get you going with what you need to achieve.

A better solution is to change how you're storing data, and define models for `Food`, `Drink` and `Other` (that last one needs a bit of thought, as Other isn't a good name for a model).

These pieces of data are clearly important enough to the application domain so they should be represented clearly. This would also allow you do have better relationships, and later do more complicated reports - easier.

For example, your `Campaign` model:

```
public function foods() {
    // You may want to model this as a many-to-many, if the food can be used with other campaigns.
    return $this->hasMany(Food::class);
}

public function drinks() {
    return $this->hasMany(Drink::class);
}
```

You could then do lots of reporting, such as 'show me all campaigns that have food, but don't have drinks':

```
$campaigns = CreativeCampaign::whereHas('foods')->whereDoesntHave('drinks')->get();
```

The [documentation on Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) may be a useful guide. I'd also recommend studying up on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) so that you can get a better understanding on how to model your data efficiently.

Hope this helps, and don't forget to mark this as the answer if you feel it adequately answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for the information - would that involve creating Models for Food, Drink etc?

Comment: My solution allows you to keep your existing data set up but personally I think having a better data structure works better - long term. I'll update my answer to add more information.

Comment: Brilliant, will get onto it.  I will award you the bounty as soon as it allows me too :-)